# When clause jenkins variable check in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to use variable from prior stage as part of when clause check in subsequent stage?.

Printing `${os_type}` is printing value without a clause. But using just `os_type` or `${os_type}` or `"${os_type}"` or `params.os_type` not matching check. Is there a way to correct this?

```
def os_type
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('stage 1') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                echo "ver=1.3.0" > ${WORKSPACE}/some_file
                echo "os_type=win" > ${WORKSPACE}/some_file
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
                steps {
                    script{         
                        os_type = sh(
                            script: "grep \"os_type\" ${WORKSPACE}/some_file | awk -F \"=\" '{print \$2}'",
                            returnStdout: true,
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('stage 3') {
               when {
                expression { "${os_type}" == 'win' }
               }
                steps {
                    echo "From stage 1 : ${os_type}"
            }
        }
    }

}
```